# Echo only gives me the first part of string

Tags: wpdb, array, meta-value

So I was pulling some meta_value and trying to use it in a mass email and tested it first by echoing what I obtain in the array. In var_dump I see the array and that it gets my correct data, but when I echo the values in the loop, they only return the first letter in the string.

```
$meta_key = 'agency_email';
$agency_emails = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s", $meta_key));
var_dump($agency_emails); //I can see the array and the full string here
foreach ($agency_emails as $ae) {
$aemail = $ae['meta_value'];
echo $aemail; //Only gives me the first part of string?
}
```

if one of my emails is 'test@test.com' it will only give me 't' in the echo. What is the reason for this and how do I get the full string? Thanks.

Comment: paste the output of your `var_dump( $agency_emails );`

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "test@test.com" }

Comment: so...$agency_emails is a numeric array with one element? And you're trying to assign a variable to an element of that array with key 'meta_value' - a key which doesn't exist? Is that what's going on here?

Comment: I also originally tried with $ae['agency_email'] and got the same result in my confusion I tried $ae['meta_value'] to see what it would give me out of curiosity. In both cases it echos 't' the first letter in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your code thusly:

```
 $meta_key = 'agency_email';
 $agency_emails = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s", $meta_key ) );
 var_dump( $agency_emails );
 foreach ( $agency_emails as $ae ) {
  echo $ae; 
 }
```